# Design ideas for Spring Batch Job better performnace

Tags: spring-batch

I have written a spring batch job and using `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`. I tried to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` but that is giving much slower performance than `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

These are main points about the job,

1.Processing part of job is most time consuming part. Its basically fires large number of `SQL SELECTs` to a different DB table than reader and writer. 
Reader and Writer doesn't take much time.Processor is very complex.

2.There is a functional requirement to write output of processor to DB as soon as processor returns a record. This is needed because
    processor finding something for writer would be rare and we need
    results immediately persisted. In a nutshell, its a business
    requirement to have `chunk size =1`

I am concerned about performance of the job. Performance increases manifold if I make processor logic a bit lightweight so I guess processor is bottleneck.

I am simply using `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to achieve parallelism. Job is supposed to run on a powerful multi processor system.

Any ideas about what all I can do more in terms of Spring Batch to make this job faster?

Job has this single step.

```
@Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            ItemReader<RemittanceVO> syncReader, ItemWriter<RemittanceClaimVO> writer,
            ItemProcessor<RemittanceVO, RemittanceClaimVO> processor) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .listener(zeroReadRowsStepExecutionListener)
                .<RemittanceVO, RemittanceClaimVO> chunk(Constants.SPRING_BATCH_CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(syncReader)
                .listener(afterReadListener)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .taskExecutor(simpleAsyntaskExecutor)
                .throttleLimit(Constants.THROTTLE_LIMIT)
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have a chunksize of 1, then there es no way to be fast. You produce so much overhead (for instance updating the batch tables for every single item). Moreover, making DB calls out of a processor has also a very negative impact on performance, since you produce again sql calls for every single item.

The key to a good performance - when it comes to work with DBs - is to reduce to number of calls send to the DB. Eg. by using batchUpdates or SQL statements that select data for the whole chunk, not for a single item (using an appropriate IN-clause).

When I have to read additional data for processing my items, I use two patterns:

- first, I try to select the additional data with a merge reader (a merge reader merges data from different readers together by having the data sorted based on the same key)
- second, If that is not possible, I use a special writer, which executes the processing part as well. This way, you can implement your Select with an appropriate IN clause which selects the data for the complete chunk. Therefore, in case of oracle, you only need one call to get the data for a thousand items.

Comment: Actually, job is about searching for a matching record in processor from a table which has more than 80 million rows. Since I can't store whole table in memory (due to table size being very large) , option that I used is to fire `SELECT` with appropriate `WHERE` clauses. For a single input value from reader, on an average there would be 200+ SELECTs fired ( i.e. there are more than 200 rules to be executed ). WHERE clause is optimized in such a way that it should take optimal time.

Comment: are those 200+ Selects always the same selects for every read item? If yes, then I would recommend to use my second pattern. doing 200+ additional db calls per read item will never lead to a satisfying performance. I mean, if you have _only_ 1000 items, you produce over 200'000 calls. My approach would reduce this to a couple of hundred calls.

Comment: no, those rules are not fixed but dynamically generated for each input to processor.

Comment: then you will have to find a way to decrease the number of db calls, if performance becomes an issue. From what you are writing, I would expect, that your batch spends around 99% of the time communicating with the db. Is there no way how you could organise your read items in a way that at least all items in a chunk use the same queries?

Comment: yes, you are correct on db part. As of now, rules are very specific to each input of processor but I will see if I can group.